# Swift parse.com messaging system to display last message of sender/receiver

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm developing a messaging system and the conversation list must display 3 things:

last message of whoever sent the message (me a.k.a. current user, or other user)
name of other user
picture of other user

I use parse.com as back end

let sentMessagesQuery = PFQuery(className: Message.parseClassName())
        sentMessagesQuery.whereKey("from", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)

```
    let receivedMessagesQuery = PFQuery(className: Message.parseClassName())
    receivedMessagesQuery.whereKey("to", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)

    let query = PFQuery.orQuery(withSubqueries: [sentMessagesQuery, receivedMessagesQuery])

    query.includeKey("from")
    query.includeKey("to")
    query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects: [PFObject]!, error: Error!)->Void in

        if(error == nil){

            for object in objects as! [Message]{

                self.messageArray.add(object)
            }

            self.messagerieTable.reloadData()

        }else{
            print("error")
        }

    })
```

The current query displays all messages.
thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getFirstObjectInBackground` to return the first object of the query which will be the last message since you sorted with Descending Order.

```
 query.getFirstObjectInBackground { (parseObject, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        guard let message = parseObject as? Message else { return }
        self.messageArray.add(message)
        self.messagerieTable.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: thx but i wont to retreive the last message of conversation with every freind